# How to rbind, arrange and format data in a list of matrices resulting from a group split

Tags: r, functional-programming, iteration

I have a `list` of `matrices` showing the results of a descriptive analysis resulting from a previous `group_split()` by a factor.

What I'd like to do is stacking corresponding `matrices` using `rbind()` with the help of a functional solution that allows for an iterating choice of corresponding `matrices`, rbinding and formatting them (i.e. setting rownames, colnames, and individual order of rows). The final step is to print the `matrices` containing the descriptive results using `kableExtra`.

My problem: Using `rbind()` within a for loop to bind and iterate over the corresponding matrix triplets to `rbind` them only produces the desired output for the last triplet, but not for all triplets. Maybe someone of you has an idea of where I'm going wrong. I have consulted similar questions here but have not found any solution to my problem.

Here is an example using a `tidyverse` and `kableExtra` package environment

```
# Some random data for an initial df
city <- rep(c(1:3), each = 4) %>% factor () # this is the splitting variable
gender <- rep(c("m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f", "m", "f")) %>% factor () # this is a factor for a later subgrouping analysis
age <- c(32, 54, 67, 35, 19, 84, 34, 46, 67, 41, 20, 75)
working_yrs <- c(16, 27, 39, 16, 2, 50, 16, 23, 48, 21, 0, 57)
income <- (working_yrs)*50

df <- data.frame(city, gender, age, working_yrs, income)

cities <- city %>% levels () %>% c () # vector needed later for a for loop


# Group splits by city (dfs -> list of lists)
df1 <- select(df, -gender) %>% 
  group_split (city, keep=FALSE)

df2 <- select (df, -income) %>%
  filter(str_detect(gender, "m")) %>% 
  select (city, age, working_yrs) %>%
  group_split (city, keep = FALSE)

df3 <- select (df, -income) %>%
  filter(str_detect(gender, "f")) %>% 
  select (city, age, working_yrs) %>%
  group_split (city, keep = FALSE)

LOL <- c(df1, df2, df3) # list of lists


# Define function for descriptive analysis (list of lists -> list of matrices)
fun_descr <- function(x) {
  c(n=sum(!is.na(x)),
    Percent=((sum(!is.na(x)))/(sum(!is.na(x)) + sum(is.na(x)))*100),
    Mean=mean(x, na.rm = TRUE),
    SD=sd(x, na.rm = TRUE),
    Median=median(x, na.rm = TRUE),
    Quantile=quantile(x, 0.25, na.rm = TRUE),
    Quantile=quantile(x, 0.75, na.rm = TRUE))
}

LOM <- lapply (LOL, function (x) {
  t(apply(x, 2, fun_descr)) %>% round(digits = 1)
})
```

So far so good, now here's the problem. My approach to `rbind()` corresponding matrix triplets belonging to the same city returns proper results for the last city only.

```
for (i in 1:length(cities)) {
  bindcity <- rbind(LOM[[i]], LOM[[i+length(cities)]], LOM[[i+(length(cities)*2)]])
}

bindcity
```

If the `for` loop or an `lapply` solution worked correctly, returning a list of rbound `matrices`, I would expect to be formatting the rows and cols of the resulting `list` of `matrices` as follows. Unfortunately, since the previous step doesn't work as expected, I couldn't test it, yet. I'm still struggling to find a first line for this function sorting each matrix's rows in the following row order 1,4,6,2,5,7,3 so that the data match the rownames shown below.

```
nicematrices <- lapply (bindcity, function (x) {
  rownames(x) <- paste(list("Age", "Working years", "Age (male)", "Working years (male)", "Age (female)", "Working years (female)", "Income"))
  colnames(x) <- paste(list("n (valid)", "% (valid)", "Mean", "SD", "Median", "25% Quantile", "75% Quantile"))
  return(x)
})
```

Final step: Print `matrices` using `kableExtra`

```
for (i in 1:length(nicematrices)) {
print(
  kable(nicematrices[[i]], caption = "Title") %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = T) %>%
    kable_styling("striped", bootstrap_options = "hover", full_width = TRUE)
)}
```

Comment: Unfortunately ```do.call``` does ```rbind``` on all ```matrices``` in the ```list``` resulting in one large ```matrix``` which is not the desired outcome, i.e. a grouped output of descriptive results for each city in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses `lapply` loops to get the desired binded matrices and the Kable output.

```
bindcity <- lapply(seq_along(cities), function(i){
  rbind(LOM[[i]], LOM[[i+length(cities)]], LOM[[i+(length(cities)*2)]])
})

nicematrices <- lapply(bindcity, function (x) {
  rownames(x) <- c("Age", "Working years", "Income", "Age (male)", "Working years (male)", "Age (female)", "Working years (female)")
  colnames(x) <- c("n (valid)", "% (valid)", "Mean", "SD", "Median", "25% Quantile", "75% Quantile")
  x
})
```

The two loops above can be simplified. However, the following `lapply` loop will not create the `bindcity` list. This is only important if this list is used after, which is not clear from the question. It is *not* used to create the Kable tables.

```
nicematrices <- lapply(seq_along(cities), function (i) {
  x <- rbind(LOM[[i]], LOM[[i+length(cities)]], LOM[[i+(length(cities)*2)]])
  rownames(x) <- c("Age", "Working years", "Income", "Age (male)", "Working years (male)", "Age (female)", "Working years (female)")
  colnames(x) <- c("n (valid)", "% (valid)", "Mean", "SD", "Median", "25% Quantile", "75% Quantile")
  x
})
```

Now for the Kable tables.

```
library(kableExtra)

kbl_list <- lapply(nicematrices, function(x){
  kbl <- kable(x, caption = "Title") %>%
    column_spec(1, bold = TRUE) %>%
    kable_styling("striped", 
                  bootstrap_options = "hover",
                  full_width = TRUE)
  print(kbl)
})
```

Comment: Don't worry about the ```bindcity``` object. It was just there to illustrate the problem. I like your concise ```lapply``` approach. But the rownames do not seem to correspond to the descriptive information, yet. Take a look at the row stating the descriptives about the age of male subjects in each city. Its descriptives belong to income, for instance. Can you make a suggestion on how to arrange the descriptive data corresponding to the order of rownames and incorporate it into your ```lapply``` suggestion?

Comment: @GRowInG `"Income"` was misplaced. It should be the 3rd string in the vector of row names. See the edit, I believe it's right, now.

Comment: Alright, that's also a way to do it :) Thanks! Say someone else reading this wonders how those rows could be ordered in another way, e.g. Age, Age(male), Age(female), Workyrs, Workyrs(male), Workyrs(female), Income. Then inserting another line below ```rbind``` could look like ```x <- x[order(c(x, y, z,...)),]```. From the```rbind``` result I would have expected ```x <- x[order(c(1,4,6,2,5,7,3)),]``` but the one which actually does the job in the correct order reads ```x <- x[order(c(1,4,7,2,5,3,6)),]```! Do you have any idea how come? It seems unlogical given row indeces of ```nicematrices```

Comment: @GRowInG I believe this has to do with the *sequence* of instructions that build `df1 - df3`, namely, `group_split`, then `LOL`, then `bindcity` (or `nicematrices` in my second wat of building it).

Comment: I did a little bit of research. The solution to ordering matrix rows is easier than I thought. I just should have left out ```order```, meaning ```x <- x[(c(1,4,6,2,5,7,3)),]``` for getting rows ordered properly. That's it!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand correctly but have you tried adding your i index in the bindcity?

```
for (i in 1:length(cities)) {
  bindcity[[i]] <- rbind(LOM[[i]], LOM[[i+length(cities)]], LOM[[i+(length(cities)*2)]])
}
```

What could be your problem here is that your loop indeed goes through all the iterations but saves only the last one if you don't make sure that for every i it saves the output. You will also need to initiate the bindcity before the loop if you are to follow this way. Overall:

```
bindcity <- c()

for (i in 1:length(cities)) {
  bindcity[[i]] <- rbind(LOM[[i]], LOM[[i+length(cities)]], LOM[[i+(length(cities)*2)]])
}
```

Here's what the above returns:

```
> bindcity

[[1]]
            n Percent   Mean    SD Median Quantile.25% Quantile.75%
age         4     100   47.0  16.5   44.5         34.2         57.2
working_yrs 4     100   24.5  11.0   21.5         16.0         30.0
income      4     100 1225.0 548.5 1075.0        800.0       1500.0
age         2     100   49.5  24.7   49.5         40.8         58.2
working_yrs 2     100   27.5  16.3   27.5         21.8         33.2
age         2     100   44.5  13.4   44.5         39.8         49.2
working_yrs 2     100   21.5   7.8   21.5         18.8         24.2

[[2]]
            n Percent   Mean     SD Median Quantile.25% Quantile.75%
age         4     100   45.8   27.8   40.0         30.2         55.5
working_yrs 4     100   22.8   20.2   19.5         12.5         29.8
income      4     100 1137.5 1007.8  975.0        625.0       1487.5
age         2     100   26.5   10.6   26.5         22.8         30.2
working_yrs 2     100    9.0    9.9    9.0          5.5         12.5
age         2     100   65.0   26.9   65.0         55.5         74.5
working_yrs 2     100   36.5   19.1   36.5         29.8         43.2

[[3]]
            n Percent   Mean     SD Median Quantile.25% Quantile.75%
age         4     100   50.8   25.1   54.0         35.8         69.0
working_yrs 4     100   31.5   26.0   34.5         15.8         50.2
income      4     100 1575.0 1299.0 1725.0        787.5       2512.5
age         2     100   43.5   33.2   43.5         31.8         55.2
working_yrs 2     100   24.0   33.9   24.0         12.0         36.0
age         2     100   58.0   24.0   58.0         49.5         66.5
working_yrs 2     100   39.0   25.5   39.0         30.0         48.0
```

Comment: Better yet, `bindcity <- vector("list", length = length(cities))` to create the entire list instead of keep calling R's memory management routines to extend the list at each iteration. Upvote.

Comment: This returns NULLs in a list. Are you sure it works as it is?

Comment: Yes, the code above is **meant** to return `NULL`'s. It just creates the list. It would replace the instruction `bindcity <- c()`.

Comment: Good to know this!